# Когда местоимение "я" можно опустить, а когда лучше этого не делать?

Tags: стилистика, местоимения

Дана пара последовательных предложений (например, из личного дневника): "Узнал сегодня, что X выходит замуж. Я воспринял это известие спокойно". В первом предложении местоимение "я" опущено, но подразумевается, во втором ─ присутствует. Хорошо ли это выглядит с точки зрения стилистики? Или лучше добавить "я" в первое предложение? И вообще, в каких случаях "я" лучше оставить, а в каких можно опустить?

Comment: Вопрос не стилистики, а психологии.
Если это действительно дневник, а не мемуары.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, существуют ли какие-то правила на этот счет. Чисто интуитивно, незачем в дневнике якать, если и так понятно, о ком идет речь. В порядке приоритетности:

**(1) Узнал сегодня, что X выходит замуж. Воспринял это известие спокойно.**

**(2) Я узнал сегодня, что X выходит замуж. Воспринял это известие спокойно.**

**(3) Узнал сегодня, что X выходит замуж. Я воспринял это известие спокойно.** Как будто хотите подчеркнуть "я", но зачем? Другие на Вашем месте реагировали бы по-другому?

**(4) Я узнал сегодня, что X выходит замуж. Я воспринял это известие спокойно.**
- Повторяющееся "я" - стилистически плохо.